# Proof required for a simple geometric problem.

Tags: geometry

The following seems to be quite obvious but a formal proof is required.

[image]

Two unequal circles $K_1$ (centered at $O$ with radius $= r$) and $K_2$ (centered at $G$ with radius $= R$) intersect at $Z$. $X$ and $Y$ are points on $K_1$ and $K_2$ respectively. $OX$ and $GY$ are produced to meet at $V$.

Consider the line pairs $[VX, ZY]$ and $[VY, ZX]$. How to prove that $(VX \ge ZY)$ or/and $(VY \ge ZX)$.

Remarks: (1) The result for ‘or’ is fine and that for ‘and’ is even better. (2) There is no need to consider special cases like $VZ$ is not in-between of $VX$ and $VY$.

---

@user21820 discovered that this request may not be true. See below.

Comment: Maybe you can assume the opposite, and then notice that if a side is shorter, then one of the angles has to smaller (than both the other angle and than a right angle). I think you could follow that through to get a contradiction...

Comment: @shardulc The two sides to be compared are located on the opposite sides of a quadrilateral (not a triangle) making the comparison (via angles) difficult.

Comment: OK I've assumed that both inequalities are not true, and I've got to $\angle V > \angle Z$. Does this help?

Comment: @shardulc I don’t know whether that can help or not. The approach I am thinking is: extend YZ to cut VX produced at Q. then ZX is an internal segment of triangle QVY with VY being the outermost line segment.

Comment: A line segment completely contained in a triangle may be longer than two of its sides.

Comment: @user21820 I am convinced by your finding.

Comment: I edited my answer to sketch how you would justify a simple condition to get both inequalities. But I still don't know the relation between those inequalities and the angle condition that *shardulc* suggested.

Comment: @shardulc I have re-written a question similar to this. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314767/another-simple-question-in-geometry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is false. Move the circles sufficiently far apart (but still intersecting) and make $V$ sufficiently close to them. Then both inequalities will be invalid. You may want to try figuring out a sufficient condition that would guarantee what you asked for.
$\def\tri{\triangle}$
$\def\ang{\angle}$
$\def\o{^\circ}$
$\def\seg#1{\overline{#1}}$

Hint:

> Look at the angle at which the circles intersect.

To get both inequalities, one sufficient condition is $\ang YZX \ge 90\o$. Together with the fact that $\ang ZXV > 90\o$ and $\ang VYZ > 90\o$, this guarantees that the line through $X$ parallel to $YZ$ intersects $\seg{VY}$ at a point $P$ such that $|XV| > |XP| > |YZ|$. Similarly for the other side. The condition *shardulc* suggested is not enough to give both of the inequalities, and the counter-example is not hard to find (I used Geogebra) but I'm unable to prove that it is enough to give at least one of the inequalities.

Comment: Is the condition $\angle V \leq \angle Z$ necessary and sufficient?

Comment: @shardulc: Your condition is not implied by just one of the inequalities nor does it imply both inequalities. However, I have no idea whether it implies at least one of the inequalities or whether both inequalities imply it.

Comment: I have re-written a question similar to this. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314767/another-simple-question-in-geometry

Comment: @user21820 both inequalities imply it (I'm almost sure about that)

Comment: @shardulc: I'd be interested to see your proof of that, if you don't mind. Feel free to post it in an answer if it's too long for a comment.

Comment: @user21820: wait, I meant to say that the converse of both inequalities implies the converse of $\angle V\leq \angle Z$, and I think it works the other way too, but here's the proof. Both inequalities are negated, and when one side is less that the other in a quadrilateral, the sum of the angles on the larger side has to be less than 180 degrees. So $\angle Y + \angle Z < 180$ and $\angle X + \angle Z < 180$. Adding these two inequalities, we can say that $\angle V - \angle Z >0$ (sum of a quadrilateral's angles).

Comment: @shardulc: Wrong. It is easy to find a quadrilateral such that one side is larger than the opposite side but the angles adjacent to the larger side is greater than 180 degrees.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @shardulc: Try; it's really not hard.