# Another simple question in Geometry

Tags: geometry

Two unequal circles $K_O$ (centered at $O$ with radius$ = r$) and $K_G$ (centered at $G$ with radius $ = R$) intersect at $Z$. $X$ and $Y$ are points on $K_O$ and $K_G$ respectively. $OX$ and $GY$ are produced to meet at $V$.

[image]

I need to prove that: $VX + VY \ge VZ = d$, say.

Case-1 [When $VX \ge ZY$ and $VY \ge ZX$]

Constructions needed: (1) Form the parallelogram $VXZV’$ such that $VX$ is translated to $V’Z$. (2) Draw circles $K_z$ (radius $= ZV’$) and $K_v$ (radius $= VY$) and let them intersect at $S$.

[image]

Then, $VX + VY = ZV’ + VY = ZS + VS \ge d$

[Extra information that assure the proposition is true:- $VX + VY = V’Z + VT = V’Z + V’V + V’T \ge V’Z + V’V \ge d$; where $T$ is the point of intersection of $K_v$ and $VV’$ produced.]

Case-2 [When $VX \le ZY$ and $VY \le ZX$]

[image]

The proof is essentially the same as that in case-1 (but without the extra information).

What worries me is:- “the proof of case-2 will fall apart if $S$ does not exist (i.e. $K_z$ and $K_v$ do not intersect at all).” Of course, if that happens, the whole proposition is false and this post can be thrown away.

My questions are then (1) Will $S$ always exist? (2) If it doesn’t, what extra condition is needed to guarantee its existence?

Comment: wow, nice visuals.

Comment: @Sawarnik Sorry. Don't understand your comment. Do you mean eventually we have 2d > VX + VY? If yes, what does that help?

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread the question.